# TypeError: "__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'"

Tags: python

Why am I getting the error in the title when I call this constructor?

I call `User(**args)` with the following dictionary as `args`:

```
{'name': u'Rose Perrone', 'ipAddress': '127.0.0.1', 'email': u'hi@gmail.com'}
```

This is the constructor:

```
def __init__(name,
             ipAddress,
             password=None,
             email=None,
             deleted=None,
             includePromoted=None,
             explicit=None):
```

Comment: Why are you omitting 'self' from the constructor definition?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: When I had `self` as the first argument, I got this error: `Python: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: Ah, that's it. You forgot `self`, so the constructor is passed the instance as `name` as well as the argument from the keyword dict.

Comment: @RosePerrone Obviously, omitting self this doesn't fix the original error, but hides it with another which has more prelevance. The original error message is confusing, but if you give the function keyword arguments it isn't prepared for, the call fails. Maybe put a `**kwargs` at the end of the function definition and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, make your first parameter `self`. You don't have to, but it is very, very common, and when someone is reading your code (like right now), it's annoying :p.

`name` is acting like `self` here. You aren't supposed to pass a value for `name` (self), because python already does that. However, you are doing this, because you have a key `name` in your dictionary. Thus, you're passing two things to one parameter, hence the error.

To fix this:

1. Firstly, **`self`** !!!!
2. But also don't forget to add in your `name` parameter.

So altogether:

```
args = {'name': u'Rose Perrone', 'ipAddress': '127.0.0.1', 'email': u'hi@gmail.com'}
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,
                 name,
                 ipAddress,
                 password=None,
                 email=None,
                 deleted=None,
                 includePromoted=None,
                 explicit=None):
                pass

MyClass(**args)
# <__main__.MyClass instance at blah>
```

Comment: When I use that, why do I get this error? `TypeError('__init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)',)`

Comment: @RosePerrone Works for me. Did you copy my solution exactly?

Comment: It works when I use this dictionary: `{'ipAddress': 'hey', 'name': 'test', 'email': 'hey'}`, but not when I use this dictionary: `{'name': u'Rose Perrone', 'twitterId': u'2818972839', 'twitterOauthToken': u'3D15689754-abcdfghj5ITfAW8ny95adfM3fqHUcrhrOarcchhcjadeftbh', 'facebookId': u'812222287391889', 'ipAddress': '127.0.0.1', 'email': u'rose@gmail.com'}`

Comment: @RosePerrone The second one won't work because there is no parameter `twitterId` in `__init__`, nor is there a `twitterOauthToken` or `facebookId` parameters

Comment: I omitted those for simplicity.

Comment: @RosePerrone Interesting. So are you using my code exactly or your own adapted to this? If the second one, could you please edit your question and include the code + full traceback

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37444/discussion-between-rose-perrone-and-haidro)